# Oracle not use extra indexes when there's an ORDER BY

Tags: oracle, indexing

I'm playing with Oracle 12 and indexes...

In a query like this:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE col1 = val1 AND col2 = val2 ORDER BY id DESC
```

(where id is the primary key of the table), Oracle always uses the index on the primary key.

So even if I create an index on the columns col1 and col2, since there's the ORDER BY statement, it doesn't use the index.

So can I infer that this is a general rule? Should I never put extra indexes in case all my queries contains "ORDER BY ID" ?

Here is my table structure:

```
ID                  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOCACHE ORDER,
USERNAME            VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)   
TYPE_A              CHAR(1 BYTE)        
TYPE_B              CHAR(1 BYTE)        
CREATED             DATE        
UPDATED             DATE    

ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
    USING INDEX TABLESPACE XXX;
```

On the table I perform only this query:

```
SELECT id, USERNAME, TYPE_A, TYPE_B, CREATED FROM table
where username = 'MYUSER' 
AND created >= TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND created <= TO_DATE('2016-06-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND TYPE_A = 1
order by ID desc;
```

One index: on pk (ID) (automatically created by oracle)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                         |     2 |   384 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| table                   |     2 |   384 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING| INDEX_PK                |    10 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Two indexes: first on pk and second on (USERNAME, CREATED, TYPE_A)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                         |     2 |   384 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| table                   |     2 |   384 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING| INDEX_PK                |    10 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the second index seems to be useless.

By the way If i remove the ORDER BY statement, Oracle uses the second index on USERNAME, CREATED, TYPE_A.

Thanks all!

Comment: why you need indexing on other columns?

Comment: "Oracle **always** uses the index on the primary key" - this not true, Oracle uses is always only on your table and dataset. Please show a structure of your table and indexes, and one can easily show you that this is not true filling the table with other data set.

Comment: Please post an explain plan for this query.

Comment: Hi, thanks all, I added some details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me just give you a counterexample which shows that there are cases where Oracle will use the second index.

```
SQL> create table tab (
  2  ID          NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOCACHE ORDER,
  3  USERNAME        VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  4  TYPE_A      CHAR(1 BYTE),
  5  TYPE_B      CHAR(1 BYTE),
  6  CREATED         DATE,
  7  UPDATED         DATE
  8  )
  9  /

Table created.

SQL> alter table tab add constraint tab_pk primary key (id) using index
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> create index SECOND_IDX on tab(username, created, type_a)
  2  /

Index created.

SQL> insert into tab(username, type_a, type_b, created)
  2  select 'OTHER_USER', '2', '2', date '2015-06-01'
  3  from all_objects, all_objects where rownum <= 1e5;

100000 rows created.

SQL> 
SQL> update tab
  2  set username = 'MYUSER',
  3      created = DATE '2016-06-01',
  4      type_a = '1'
  5   where id = 50000;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> begin
  2     dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => USER,
  3        tabname => 'TAB',
  4        estimate_percent => 100,
  5        method_opt => 'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS'
  6     );
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> set autotrace traceonly exp
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT id, USERNAME, TYPE_A, TYPE_B, CREATED FROM tab
  2  where username = 'MYUSER'
  3  AND created >= TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
  4  AND created <= TO_DATE('2016-06-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
  5  AND TYPE_A = '1'
  6  order by ID desc;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3658386757

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |            |     1 |    29 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                       |            |     1 |    29 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TAB        |     1 |    29 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | SECOND_IDX |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this case the reason to use the second index is the extremely high selectivity (one row out of 100000).

Comment: Thank you, so it's better to place that second index in any case. That is what i was looking for.

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried your code and comparing with mine, there's something weird... 

The only difference is that you use "primary key(id)" and I use 

ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOCACHE ORDER 

in the create table definition, and 

ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_pk
PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
USING INDEX TABLESPACE XXX;

In my case Oracle keeps using the index generated on the id column, in your case it uses the SECOND_IDX...

Comment: Anyway I managed to create a situation in which Oracle uses the second composite index when the record extracted by the query are much less the total number of rows stored in the table..

Answer (score 3):

Well, in short answer - no, but we can't give you a general rule, because every time will be different as to a lot of different variable. For more specific answer you should include an explain plan of this query, and we'll have a better picture on why it doesn't use the index.

Oracle will know to use this index as long as `ID` column will be specified first .

You shouldn't add unnecessary indexes for selects that will only occur once in a lot of time or those that are slow, but not too slow. You should only add indexes related to the most common selects/updates that occurs on this table.

If a select with filters on `col1` and `col2` is repeatedly , then most likely(again, I don't know what other processes you are doing on this table) an index on all 3 columns will be better :

```
(ID,Col1,Col2)
```